# (License google-gdk-license) this license doesn't exist when installing and set up flutter on widows?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have installed flutter for windows, and android sdk from android std manager, i tesed the flutter plateform in the cmd and every things ok, but when checking the flutter docotor in cmd, i have a warning messagme tha  there is one lincence not accepted (License google-gdk-license)
please help me to complete the instalation process.

[image: the error image]

solving my problem by providing me with the right answer

Comment: Have you accepted all the android license? 
You have to accept all of it ,then run `flutter doctor` again, everything should be ok

Comment: I did, android sdk, android sdk manager, accept licenses and then copy them to the environment variables to declare the path, and every things ok unless that licenses